# Testing Oracle function which returns a sys-refcursor in DataGrip

Tags: oracle, datagrip

I have this assignment to implement a Oracle function to return a search for books.  I have it all coded up but am struggling to figure out how best to test the function.  While it might be better as a procedure, the specs call for a function.  Here is the code I am trying to test:

```
  FUNCTION SEARCH_BOOK(PI_TITLE_KEYWORD IN          TRNG_BOOK.TITLE%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
                       PI_PUBLISH_DT_LOWER_BOUND IN TRNG_BOOK.PUBLISH_DT%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
                       PI_PUBLISH_DT_UPPER_BOUND IN TRNG_BOOK.PUBLISH_DT%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
                       PI_GENRE_NAME IN             TRNG_GENRE.GENRE_NM%TYPE DEFAULT NULL)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
    IS
    PO_RESULT SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN

    OPEN PO_RESULT FOR
      WITH
        LATE_SHIPMENTS_COUNT_LST AS (
          SELECT
            I.BOOK_ID,
            COUNT(*) AS COUNT
          FROM
            TRNG_ORDR_ITEM I
              LEFT OUTER JOIN TRNG_ORDR O ON O.ORDR_ID = I.ORDR_ID
          WHERE
            EXTRACT(DAY FROM COALESCE(O.SHPMT_TSTP, SYSDATE) - O.ORDR_TSTP) > 2
          GROUP BY I.BOOK_ID
        )
      SELECT
        B.BOOK_ID                AS BOOK_ID,
        B.ISBN                   AS ISBN,
        B.TITLE                  AS TITLE,
        B.PUBLISH_DATE           AS PUBLISH_DATE,
        B.PUBLISHER_NAME         AS PUBLISHER_NAME,
        B.COST                   AS COST,
        B.RETAIL_PRICE           AS RETAIL_PRICE,
        B.GENRE_NAME             AS GENRE_NAME,
        B.AUTHOR_LIST            AS AUTHOR_LIST,
        B.TOTAL_QUANTITY_ORDERED AS TOTAL_QUANTITY_ORDERED,
        COALESCE(SC.COUNT, 0)    AS LATE_SHIPMENTS_COUNT
      FROM
        TRNG_BOOK_DETAIL_VW B
          LEFT OUTER JOIN LATE_SHIPMENTS_COUNT_LST SC ON B.BOOK_ID = SC.BOOK_ID
      WHERE
          (PI_TITLE_KEYWORD IS NULL OR B.TITLE IN '%' || PI_TITLE_KEYWORD || '%')
      AND (PI_PUBLISH_DT_LOWER_BOUND IS NULL OR PI_PUBLISH_DT_LOWER_BOUND < B.PUBLISH_DATE)
      AND (PI_PUBLISH_DT_UPPER_BOUND IS NULL OR PI_PUBLISH_DT_UPPER_BOUND > B.PUBLISH_DATE)
      AND (PI_GENRE_NAME IS NULL OR B.GENRE_NAME IN '%' || PI_GENRE_NAME || '%');

    RETURN PO_RESULT;
  END SEARCH_BOOK;
```

And I am trying to call it with this, which runs without errors, but no output.  I am wondering... without taking hours to write the code, how can I get some type of output?  For the record I am using DataGrip.

```
DECLARE
  RESULT                    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  PI_TITLE_KEYWORD          VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL ;
  PI_PUBLISH_DT_LOWER_BOUND DATE           := NULL ;
  PI_PUBLISH_DT_UPPER_BOUND DATE           := NULL ;
  PI_GENRE_NAME             VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL ;
BEGIN
  RESULT := TRNG_BOOKS.SEARCH_BOOK(
      PI_TITLE_KEYWORD => PI_TITLE_KEYWORD,
      PI_PUBLISH_DT_LOWER_BOUND => PI_PUBLISH_DT_LOWER_BOUND,
      PI_PUBLISH_DT_UPPER_BOUND => PI_PUBLISH_DT_UPPER_BOUND,
      PI_GENRE_NAME => PI_GENRE_NAME
    );

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

What's your Oracle version?

In actual supported versions you can use `dbms_sql.return_result()`:

```sql
DECLARE
  RESULT                    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  PI_TITLE_KEYWORD          VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL ;
  PI_PUBLISH_DT_LOWER_BOUND DATE           := NULL ;
  PI_PUBLISH_DT_UPPER_BOUND DATE           := NULL ;
  PI_GENRE_NAME             VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL ;
BEGIN
  RESULT := TRNG_BOOKS.SEARCH_BOOK(
      PI_TITLE_KEYWORD => PI_TITLE_KEYWORD,
      PI_PUBLISH_DT_LOWER_BOUND => PI_PUBLISH_DT_LOWER_BOUND,
      PI_PUBLISH_DT_UPPER_BOUND => PI_PUBLISH_DT_UPPER_BOUND,
      PI_GENRE_NAME => PI_GENRE_NAME
    );
   dbms_sql.return_result(RESULT);
END;
```

Comment: According to the DB, it is version 19.6.0.0.0.  I tried adding **dbms_sql.return_result(RESULT);** and I simply get **[99999][17283] No resultset available**, but as @Kumar said, I am using DataGrip IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You have the basics correct; your code should run as is. What you are missing a validating that AFTER you have the result. The easiest iterate the ref cursor after return from your function. But for that you need to define a variables to hold the values while iterating.

```
declare
  type book_search_rec is record 
       ( book_id                  trng_book_detail_vw.book_id%type
       , isbn                     trng_book_detail_vw.isbn%type
       , title                    trng_book_detail_vw.title%type
       , publish_date             trng_book_detail_vw.publish_date%type
       , publisher_name           trng_book_detail_vw.publisher_name%type
       , cost                     trng_book_detail_vw.cost%type
       , retail_price             trng_book_detail_vw.retail_price%type
       , genre_name               trng_book_detail_vw.genre_name%type
       , author_list              trng_book_detail_vw.author_list%type
       , total_quantity_ordered   trng_book_detail_vw.total_quantity_ordered%type
       , late_shipments_count     interger
       );
  po_rec                    book_search_rec;  

  result                    sys_refcursor;
  pi_title_keyword          varchar2(4000) := null ;
  pi_publish_dt_lower_bound date           := null ;
  pi_publish_dt_upper_bound date           := null ;
  pi_genre_name             varchar2(4000) := null ;
  
  
begin
  result := trng_books.search_book(
      pi_title_keyword          => pi_title_keyword,
      pi_publish_dt_lower_bound => pi_publish_dt_lower_bound,
      pi_publish_dt_upper_bound => pi_publish_dt_upper_bound,
      pi_genre_name             => pi_genre_name
    );

  loop
    fetch result into po_rec;
    exit when result%notfound;
    
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Book Id: ' ||  po_rec.book_id); 
    dbms_output.put_line( '   ISBN: ' ||  po_rec.isbn;
    dbms_output.put_line( '  TITLE: ' ||  po_rec.title;
    .
    .
    .
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Late Shipments: ' ||  po_rec.late_shipments_count;
  end loop;              
end;
```